# surface pen stylus doesnt recognize hover in chrome

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem related to hover pseudo not working. Problem is with Surface pad's chrome browser. Hover effect is working fine in rest of the browsers but not working in chrome. I am using surface pen to check the hover.

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
a:hover{cursor:pointer; background:red;}
```

Comment: Try adding `a:focus {cursor:pointer; background:red;}`

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to make sure that your hover anchor has an `href` on it to make it touchable. You can do this with either `href="#"`  or `href="javascript:void"` , then you need to add `aria-haspopup="true"`  to tell the device that after the user releases the tap, whatever was visible should remain visible until another interaction.

Comment: Try to add touch-action: auto; also maybe it solves it.  and also catch your <a> tag like ul li a:hover......

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Actually earlier i was having a problem on touch devices. Hover effects were working on touch and was not changing on untouch the area.Hover effect stick with the touch and didn't go back. so on touch devices i changed the :hover into :active.